# Term describing code that is solely there to fix problems of a suboptimal architecture

Tags: architecture, terminology, anti-patterns

So, there are terms describing pieces of code based on their purpose - like for example:

```
"Boilerplate Code": sections of code that have to be included in many places with little or no alteration
```

or

```
"Glue Code":  code that does not contribute any functionality towards meeting the program's requirements, but instead serves solely to "glue together" different parts of code that would not otherwise be compatible
```

Now, if you work with a project that was not properly engineered, you find yourself often adding code (like setting state flags and checking for them in various places) that solely fixes/circumvents arising problems that a properly engineered/refactored architecture would not exhibit.

Is there any term describing such "code that is only necessary because the architecture is bad"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: How is this not about programming?

Comment: Sounds like a linguistic problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had my own term for this: "ball of sticky tape" or "ball of bandages".

Some anti patterns that might describe this :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stovepipe_system

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet (or accidental complexity)

and the old classic :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: I use the term "hot mess" frequently because that's eventually what the code like these becomes without disciplined developers.